# How to search certain lines from a text file in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to collect the error report from client servers and store it in master server. If an error is reported then it is updated in  output.error file  in master server. So how do I search this file for below lines.
If these lines are present then I will perform certain tasks.
Sample Errors:-

```
3C81E43F   0203220415 P U topsvcs        Late in sending heartbeat
4B436A3D   0318052119 T H fscsi1         LINK ERROR
BFE4C025   0302224219 P H sysplanar0     UNDETERMINED ERROR
```

Actual output.error file

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Errpt report for 192.168.1.52

3C81E43F   0203220415 P U topsvcs        Late in sending heartbeat  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Errpt report for 192.168.1.85

DCB47997   0318052119 T H hdisk11        DISK OPERATION ERROR
4B436A3D   0318052119 T H fscsi1         LINK ERROR
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Errpt report for 192.168.5.62 

BFE4C025   0302224219 P H sysplanar0     UNDETERMINED ERROR
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Errpt report for 192.168.7.89 

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Errpt report for 192.168.5.87
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Your problem is unclear: what differentiates the three lines you cite from the fourth error line, the disk operation error?  I see several possible ways to differentiate the lines, but you haven't clarified which might be right, let alone supplied a coding problem.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like a typical regex scenario:

```
with open('logfile.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match('___your_regex___', line):
            do_something(line)
```

Comment: This is more of a comment, boiling down to "use regex".

Comment: with open("/tmp/output.txt") as ERROR:
    for line in ERROR:
        if re.match('(\w+\s+\d+)' , line):
            server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
            server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
            server.quit()
     break